# ツリー構造の情報を作りたい

Tags: c#

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

あるデータをツリー構造のデータを作ろうとしているのですが、
うまくロジックをくめずにおります。
イメージとしては
画像のようなA～Fのデータをツリーで持ちたく考えており、

データとしてA～Fをもつデータ配列と
矢印線のデータ配列があります。
A～Fのデータはそれぞれ、つながる線のデータをもち、
矢印線のデータは矢印の先にどのデータA～Fにつながっているかの情報を持っています。

図のように矢印のデータにIN、OUTがわかるようであれば若干楽になるのですが
それがない状態です。
A～FのデータはAがトップのデータであるということのみがわかるようなものになっています。

```
List<Item> items;   A～Fのリスト情報
List<Arrow> arrows; 矢印線のリスト情報


    public class Element
    {
            public int Id;
            public int Parent;
            public IList Children;
    }
```

～～

```
ObservableCollection<Element> tree = new ObservableCollection<Element>();

Element element = new Element();
element.Id = items[0].Id;
itemsからA（トップ）の情報を取得し、つながるアイテムデータのリストを取得する
element.Childrenに取得したリストを設定
// ツリー情報にエレメントを追加
tree.Add(element);
```

つながるアイテムデータのリスト分、同じような処理をループして行うことになると思うのですが、どのようにメソッドを分けていいのかが整理できずにおります。

説明が下手で申し訳ないのですが、アドバイスいただけると助かります。

Answer (score 1):

ルートノードとエッジの有無のみが分かっているとのことですので、

```
// Element root;
// Element[] nodes;
var done = new List<Element>() { root };
var undone = nodes.Where(e => e != root).ToList();
```

のような要領で処理済み・未処理のコレクションを用意し、順次親子関係を対応させながら移していく形が良いと思います。

```
// 未処理ノードが存在する間繰り返す
while (undone.Any())
{
    // 未処理ノードを一個ずつ取り出す
    for (var i = 0; i < undone.Count; i++)
    {
        var n = nodes[i];

        var parent = done.FirstOrDefault(e => エッジがあるか判定(e, n));

        if (parent != null)
        {
            // 親が処理済みノードに見つかった場合は各プロパティを設定する
            parent.Children.Add(n);
            n.Parent = parent;

            // 処理済みノードに移動する
            done.Add(n);
            undone.RemoveAt(i);

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

なお`Element`型の`Parent`は`Element`型、`Children`は`Collection<Element>`型にし、継承して`AddItem`他のメソッドをオーバーライドし、`Parent`が自動設定されるようにする設計が良いと思います。

```
public class Element
{
    public int Id;
    public Element Parent { get; private set; }

    private Collection<Element> _Children;
    public Collection<Element> Children
        => _Children ?? (_Children = new ElementCollection(this));

    private class ElementCollection : Collection<Element>
    {
        private readonly Element Parent;
        public ElementCollection(Element parent)
        {
            Parent = parent;
        }

        protected override AddItem(int index, Element item)
        {
            if (item.Parent != null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }
            item.Parent = Parent;
            super.AddItem(index, item);
        }
        // TODO: SetItem, RemoveItem, ClearItemも実装する
    }
}
```